# TYPO3: page in browser other than in preview or in page edit

Tags: preview, typo3

I'm experiencing a very strange problem. The user sees in the browser another content of a subpage than the page editor has defined. I have no idea where TYPO3 gets the wrong content. If I preview the page from the editor it is everything correct. But from the view of a normal visitor of the page I see the wrong things.

Following TypoScript:

```
config {
// Administrator settings
admPanel    = {$config.adminPanel}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are some hidden or user restricted elements, they will be shown as long as you're logged in the backend as well (Maybe check the admin panel preferences, take a look here: http://typo3.org/1215.0.html )

Comment: Yes, there is a hidden element, which content has been shown. Now I've cleared the caches (including from real url), edited some pages and now it shows me the correct page content. I don't know why but it works now. Isn't it the normal case that if a user edits a page, he is logged in the backend? So it seems it is a bug by Typo3?